# How to add columns dynamically?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following data that is used to calculate daily event. The number column varies on a daily basis, for example Day one can be 1 to 5, day two 1 to 8, day three one to 10 etc. Hence, I used dynamic pivot to get the columns and insert it into a temp table ##NO. from the table I want to add up 1 to Nth columns value to get the grand total.

Data

```
CREATE TABLE ##TBL (Number INT, Months VARCHAR(10), Total INT)
INSERT INTO ##TBL VALUES
(3,'Dec',1),(10,'Dec',1),(8,'Dec',1),(6,'Mar',1),(9,'Mar',1),(6,'Mar',1),(3,'Dec',1),(5,'Mar',1),(3,'Mar',1),
(2,'Mar',1),(10,'Dec',1),(7,'Mar',1),(3,'Mar',1),(6,'Dec',1),(4,'Mar',1),(9,'Dec',1),(1,'Mar',1),(3,'Mar',1),
(5,'Dec',1),(9,'Dec',1),(5,'Mar',1),(8,'Mar',1),(7,'Mar',1),(5,'Mar',1),(4,'Mar',1),(8,'Mar',1),(3,'Mar',1),
(7,'Mar',1),(5,'Mar',1),(2,'Mar',1),(6,'Mar',1),(2,'Mar',1),(8,'Dec',1),(1,'Mar',1),(5,'Mar',1),(6,'Mar',1),
(8,'Mar',1),(3,'Mar',1),(9,'Dec',1),(5,'Dec',1),(8,'Dec',1),(7,'Dec',1),
(5,'Dec',1)
```

pivot table to produce the output

```
DECLARE @Numb AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @Numb =(SELECT SUBSTRING(
(
    SELECT distinct', ' + QUOTENAME(Number) AS 'data()'
        FROM ##TBL
        FOR XML PATH('')        
), 2 , 9999) As nums)

SET @query =
'SELECT * 
INTO ##NO
FROM ##TBL
        PIVOT
        ( SUM(Total) FOR Number IN ('+@Numb+')) PV'

EXEC (@query)
SELECT 
*,
ISNULL([1],0)+ISNULL([2],0)+ISNULL([3],0)+ISNULL([4],0)+ISNULL([5],0)+ISNULL([6],0)+ISNULL([7],0)+
ISNULL([8],0)+ISNULL([9],0)+ISNULL([10],0) AS Grand_Total

FROM ##NO
DROP TABLE ##NO
```

the current output

```
Months  1    10  2    3  4    5 6   7   8   9   Grand_Total
 Dec    NULL 2   NULL 2  NULL 3 1   1   3   3    15
 Mar    2   NULL 3    5  2    5 4   3   3   1    28
```

Is there a way I can dynamically sum the columns whenever the columns decrease or increase at the end?
The columns always start from 1,2,3….n and I am not really concern about the column order

Desired ouput day 1

```
Months  1     2     3   4     5  Grand_Total
Dec     NULL  NULL  2   NULL  3  5
Mar     2     3     5   2     5  17
```

Desired ouput day 2

```
Months  1   2     3  Grand_Total        
Dec    NULL NULL  2  2      
Mar     2   3     5  10
```

what i want is when ever the number column data increase or decrease. i want to be able to add them up. Sometimes the number start from 1 end in 5, another time 1 to 7 another time 1 to 8 etc

Comment: Use the same technique you used to build the list of columns but build the SUM code.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking, can you edit your question and add an example of your desired output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this to get the sum dynamically.

```
declare @SUM nvarchar(max) = ''

SELECT @SUM = @SUM + 'ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME(Number) + ',0)+'
FROM ##TBL
group by Number

select @SUM = left(@SUM, len(@SUM) - 1)
```

Then adding it to your query is pretty simple.

```
SET @query =
'SELECT *, Grand_Total = ' + @SUM
+ 'INTO ##NO
FROM ##TBL
        PIVOT
        ( SUM(Total) FOR Number IN ('+@Numb+')) PV'
```

So the fully functional code would look like this.

```
CREATE TABLE ##TBL (Number INT, Months VARCHAR(10), Total INT)
INSERT INTO ##TBL VALUES
(3,'Dec',1),(10,'Dec',1),(8,'Dec',1),(6,'Mar',1),(9,'Mar',1),(6,'Mar',1),(3,'Dec',1),(5,'Mar',1),(3,'Mar',1),
(2,'Mar',1),(10,'Dec',1),(7,'Mar',1),(3,'Mar',1),(6,'Dec',1),(4,'Mar',1),(9,'Dec',1),(1,'Mar',1),(3,'Mar',1),
(5,'Dec',1),(9,'Dec',1),(5,'Mar',1),(8,'Mar',1),(7,'Mar',1),(5,'Mar',1),(4,'Mar',1),(8,'Mar',1),(3,'Mar',1),
(7,'Mar',1),(5,'Mar',1),(2,'Mar',1),(6,'Mar',1),(2,'Mar',1),(8,'Dec',1),(1,'Mar',1),(5,'Mar',1),(6,'Mar',1),
(8,'Mar',1),(3,'Mar',1),(9,'Dec',1),(5,'Dec',1),(8,'Dec',1),(7,'Dec',1),
(5,'Dec',1)

DECLARE @Numb AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @Numb =(SELECT SUBSTRING(
(
    SELECT distinct', ' + QUOTENAME(Number) AS 'data()'
        FROM ##TBL
        FOR XML PATH('')        
), 2 , 9999) As nums)

declare @SUM nvarchar(max) = ''

SELECT @SUM = @SUM + 'ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME(Number) + ',0)+'
FROM ##TBL
group by Number


select @SUM = left(@SUM, len(@SUM) - 1)

SET @query =
'SELECT *, Grand_Total = ' + @SUM
+ 'INTO ##NO
FROM ##TBL
        PIVOT
        ( SUM(Total) FOR Number IN ('+@Numb+')) PV'

select @query

EXEC (@query)

select * from ##NO

DROP TABLE ##NO

drop table ##TBL
```